# Error: yard not installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, redmine, yard

I have a problem with redmine plugin migration. While migrating:

```
   exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get errors:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/htmlentities-4.3.1/lib/htmlentities/mappings/expanded.rb:465: warning: key "inodot" is duplicated and overwritten on line 466
yard not installed (gem install yard)
Migrating ...
...
```

Most interesting, that

```
sudo gem install yard
```

gives

```
...
Successfully installed yard-0.9.5
Done installing documentation for yard after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

but after that

```
$ bundle show yard
Could not find gem 'yard'.
Did you mean yard?
```

So how should I install yard?

I have installed Redmine V3.3.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 with apache2 and passenger, Ruby V2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo gem install yard` installs the gem into 1) global and 2) root-user gem scope. It has nothing to do with your local user-wide redmine application.

Did you run `bundle install` there in redmine dir? If no, run it, it will fix everything.

If yes, this should be a redmine issue, open it's `Gemfile` with an editor of your choice and put there `gem 'yard'`.

If none of the above helped, that might be also an issue with your local bundle config, preventing installing of some environments by default. Examine and (it should be safe) delete file `.bundle/config` inside redline root directory.

Comment: user@redmine:/var/www/redmine$ bundle install
Your Gemfile lists the gem redmine_extensions (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
...
Bundle complete! 39 Gemfile dependencies, 57 gems now installed.
Gems in the groups development, test and rmagick were not installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
user@redmine:/var/www/redmine$ bundle show yard
Could not find gem 'yard'.
Did you mean yard?

Comment: Yes I have tried "bundle install", removing ".bundle/config" gave an error with installing rmagic. 'gem "yard"' gave warning of dublicate. I have tried allso 'sudo gem list p' (as I have installed yard with sudo), but it is not there.

Comment: It helped!!!! I have removed config, installed rmagic by "sudo apt-get install libmagick++-dev" then "bundle install and "exec rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production" gave no yard problem! Than you very much!